# untarred files on server has different owner

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, permissions, tar

I am creating a tar gzipp'ed archive on my local machine (as user1) using the following commands:

> user1@devmachine:~/$ tar czpf
>   dir.tar.gz thedirectory

on the server, I untar it (as user 2) using the command

> user2@servermachine:~/$ tar xzpf
>   dir.tar.gz

I find that the extracted files are owned by another user (say user3)

What is the logic that is used to determine file ownership if the owner of the extracted file is not a user on the target machine?

I am running Ubuntu 10.0.4 on both machines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 --same-owner
       try extracting files with the same ownership

 --no-same-owner
       extract files as yourself
```